# Excel text formatting

Tags: excel

I need some help guys, I tried searching for this but cant find the correct keywords to find the right solution.

So I currently have a column with text values sort of like this:

```
1A
1B
2A
2C
10A
10B
120A
120B
Etc.
```

What I need is to format them into something like this

```
001A-XXXX
....
....
010A-YYY
...
...
120A-ZZZZZ
```

So, I got the data after the dash figured out. The thing is I need the data before the dash to always be 4 digits in the format shown above. I can for example =concatenate("00", A19, "-") and it works for the single digit numbers like "1A" because it makes it "001A-" however this would make the double and triple digit #s "0010A-" and "00100A-" which I can't have.

Any help on this issue?
Thanks in advance for your help and let me know if I need to provide more info, Im not really well versed in excel.

Comment: Is it always a single letter at the end of the text values like A, B etc?

Comment: Yes sir it is. Single letter ranging from A thru G

Comment: what is the XXXX, YYY, and ZZZZZ? or do you only care about the format of everything before `-`?

Comment: As of now I figured out everthing after the "-" i am trying to figure out how to format everything before it. But theyre essentially just a short description of each value

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more efficient way to do this, but you could probably use a nested IF statement with a length function as follows:

=IF(LEN(cellRef)=1, Concatenate("000",cellRef,"-"), IF(LEN(cellRef)=2, Concatenante("00",cellRef,"-"), ...........

Edit: another option is as follows:

=LEFT(cellRef&REPT("0",4),4)

Comment: Ok this makes sense. But i see what you mean by saying there might be a more efficient way. I will definitely try this if I dont find one. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: not sure if you saw my edit, but it works on a similar concept as Tom Sharpe's below. Glad you found a solution!

Comment: Ahh i did not see that. I found the solution but ill try this as well to see which works better for my purposes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),"000")&RIGHT(A1)
```

or

```
=REPT("0",4-LEN(A1))&A1
```

Comment: Wow these both worked to perfection. I need to look up the LEN and REPT functions as im not familiar. But thank you so much!